# Which of those different update methods should I call to make components appear after being added to a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, jcheckbox

In this simple code if I click the button a few times a few JCheckBoxes will be added to the JPanel. However the display is not updated unless right after `add("TEST")` I call either `revalidate()` (just `invalidate()` won't work), or `updateFrame()`. Also, if I use `revalidate()`, the JCheckBoxes appear but the JPanel is not resized. I'm also aware of the `repaint()` method, but I'm not sure how to use it or those other methods.

What is the relationship between those component update methods so I can achieve the minimum I want (the JCheckBoxes to appear and the JPanel to be resized)?

How could I simplify the code?

```
public class UserInterface2 {

    private final JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private JPanel panel;
    
    public UserInterface2() {
        
        frame = new JFrame("Test App");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        createButton();
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    
    private void updateFrame() {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private void createButton() {
        button = new JButton("Text");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                add("TEST");
                panel.revalidate();
                //updateFrame();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void show() {
        updateFrame();
    }

    private void add(String text) {
        panel.add(new JCheckBox(text));
    }
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new UserInterface2().show());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPanel will resize, but you're not seeing it because it is constrained by the JFrame that holds it, which can't resize without explicitly telling it to do so.

Suggestions:

1. Put the JPanel inside of a JScrollPane which will allow the JPanel to resize as components are added (and `revalidate()` is called) or
2. Call `pack()` on the enclosing top-level  window, here a JFrame, after adding components to the JPanel which will re-size the entire GUI.

Also consider

- giving the JPanel a GridLayout(0, 1)...
- ...embedding it in the BorderLayout.PAGE_START position of another BorderLayout-using JPanel...
- ...then adding that JPanel to the scroll pane or to the BorderLayout.CENTER position of the JFrame's contentPane. This will compress the added components to the top of the JPanel.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UserInterface3 {
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    
    public UserInterface3() {
        JPanel wrapperPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        wrapperPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);       
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(wrapperPanel);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        
        JButton addCheckBoxBtn = new JButton("Add CheckBox");
        addCheckBoxBtn.addActionListener(e -> addCheckBox());
        addCheckBoxBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(addCheckBoxBtn);       
        
        
        mainPanel.add(scrollPane);
        mainPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);     
    }
    
    private void addCheckBox() {
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("Test"));
        mainPanel.revalidate();
    }

    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            UserInterface3 ui3 = new UserInterface3();
            frame.add(ui3.getMainPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose the best approach will eliminate the need for `revalidate()/updateFrame()` and also will be simpler (no adding JScrollPane for instance), so I guess that will be the last one, am I right?

Comment: @Piovezan: go with the easiest to maintain and use, not necessarily the up-front simplest. Myself, I'd probably put it into a JScrollPane using the Gridlayout.

Comment: @Piovezan: for example

Comment: Thanks. Great example. So the `revalidate()` call is necessary anyway.

Comment: @Piovezan: `revalidate()` is necessary any time you add or remove a component to or from a container since you need to reactivate the layout manager of that container and all nested containers that it holds. Sometimes `repaint()` must follow, especially if removing components in order to clean up "dirty pixels"

Comment: *" I'd probably put it into a JScrollPane"* I'd definitely put them in a `JList` and put **that** into a `JScrollPane`..

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code, slightly modified, with unnecessary things removed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UserInterface2 {

    private JButton button;
    private JPanel panel;

    public UserInterface2() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test App");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        createButton();
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize (200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createButton() {
        button = new JButton("Text");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                add("TEST");
                panel.revalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    private void add(String text) {
        panel.add(new JCheckBox(text));
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new UserInterface2());
    }
}
```

No show(), no updateFrame().
The problem was, that your Panel in the center had no content, therefore wasn't drawn, occupied no space. I used `frame.setSize (200, 200);` to enforce a size > 0.

Now you see the Checkboxes appear until you added to many. But if you resize the frame, they too become visible. But `panel.revalidate ()` is necessary.